# Remove Javascript Tooltip Offset For Nicer Hover Grow Effect

Tags: javascript, hover, tooltip, position, offset

I'm trying to accomplish something and will appreciate any and all help provided!

I have a tooltip code that on hover of an image, the image appears in the tooltip with an offset position via JS. Instead of offsetting the position of the hovered image in the tooltip, I want the image in the tooltip be displayed with no offsets, [EXACTLY like the hover effect you see in this example](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/image-zoom/).  I need the position of the tooltip to not be offset at all, just be exactly on top of the image. I'm not sure how to accomplish this since the example code uses css and I need it working with this tooltip in JS.

Here's the tooltip code:

```
too = tooo = bi = an = null; document.onmousemove = document.onmouseover = toolt;
function toolt(a) {
if(bi) {
    y = bi.offsetTop+bi.height-20;
    x = bi.offsetLeft+bi.width-12;
} else {
    y = (document.all) ? window.event.y + document.body.scrollTop  : a.pageY;
    x = (document.all) ? window.event.x + document.body.scrollLeft : a.pageX;
}
a = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.body.offsetHeight;
b = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.body.offsetWidth;
if (too != null) {
    if(too.offsetWidth+x+35-document.body.scrollLeft > b) x=document.body.scrollLeft+b-too.offsetWidth-35; too.style.left = (x+12)+"px";
    if(too.offsetHeight+y+40-document.body.scrollTop > a) y=y-too.offsetHeight-30; too.style.top = (y+20)+"px"; }
}
function htoo(i) { if(too)  too.style.display  = "none"; if(bi) bi.style.display = an ? "block" : "none"; tooo = false;}
function stoo(i) { if(tooo) tooo.style.display = "none"; if(bi) bi.style.display = an ? "block" : "none"; too = tooo = document.getElementById(i); too.style.display = "block"; if(bi = document.getElementById(i+"b")) bi.style.display="block";
}
```

How can I accomplish this with the given code, any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at the JS code in the page you linked?

Comment: Yes, I have, but I just need to remove the offsets in the provided tooltip code. The JS in the tooltip is too complicated for me. I just want to edit the code provided above to display the position of the tooltip over the image instead of offset it. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sure can tweak it to be better, but here is a **proof of concept**.
*Note: Your images' style should be `position: relative`*

**Usage ([Demo](http://jsbin.com/iyavu3/10/))**

```
FancyZoom("container");
```

​
**Constructor**

```
function FancyZoom(container, options) {
  container = container || document;
  if (typeof container == "string") {
    container = document.getElementById(container);
  }

  function isNodeName(el, name) {
    return el.nodeName.toLowerCase() === name;
  }    

  function getTarget(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    return e.target || e.srcElement;
  }

  // image {mouseover} event handler (delegated)
  container.onmouseover = function(e) {
    var el = getTarget(e);
    if (isNodeName(el, "img")) {
      zoomIn(el);
      // image {mouseout} event handler
      el.onmouseout = function(e) {
        zoomOut(el);
        el.onmouseout = null;
      };  
    }
  };
}
```

**Animation** <sup>([emile.js](https://github.com/madrobby/emile))</sup>

```
function zoomIn(thumb) {
    thumb.style.zIndex = 10;
    emile( thumb,
      "width:"  + 174 + "px;" +
      "height:" + 174 + "px;" +
      "margin-left:" + -37 + "px;" +
      "margin-top:"  + -37 + "px;",
      { duration: 200 }
    );
}

function zoomOut(thumb) {
    thumb.style.zIndex = 1;
    emile( thumb,
      "width:"  + 100 + "px;" +
      "height:" + 100 + "px;" +
      "margin-left:" + 0 + "px;" +
      "margin-top:"  + 0 + "px;",
      { duration: 100 }
    );

}
```

*Tested On: IE7+, FF2+, Safari 4+, Chrome, Opera*

Comment: Also you can calculate margins by the formula as simple as: `mleft = -(large_w-small_w)/2`

Comment: Wow, galambalazs, that was quick. But that doesn't use the tooltip code. The tooltip code variable names are solid as a lot of things rely heavily on it, and so are the x,y variables. I just don't know how to edit that tooltip code provided to remove the offset entirely so the position of the tooltip will not be offset and follow the mouse, instead, it will be in the same place of the big hover effect. Technically, it's removing the offset, so the tooltip doesn't follow the mouse with a predefined amount of pixels, and instead, the tooltip will appear in the same position as the hovered image.

Comment: You can't expect anyone to figure out what your variables mean, like `a`, `bi`, `too`, `tooo`, `toolt`...

Comment: Also I told you what you need to remove full page offsets. Make the images `position:relative` then on `mouseover` adjust their dimensions and margins. The formula for margins is in my first comment. Don't be lazy. I did the hard work for you already. :)

Comment: The thing is, it's not only the image, on hover of the image, the tooltip displays the image and some html text under it, sort of the new google images. I am using the wz_tooltip.js by walter zorn, found here: http://web.archive.org/web/20080103025045/www.walterzorn.com/tooltip/tooltip_e.htm but the above .js overwrites the values. I contacted the author and will get back within the week and maybe post a sample of the entire project within the week. Thanks galambalazs for everything so far!

Comment: Sorry it took so long, here is a sample: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539816/grow-images-on-hover-like-google-images