# Grow Images on Hover like Google Images

Tags: image, hover, tooltip, onmouseover

Hey everyone, I am trying to accomplish something with images growing on hover like the fancy grow mouseover effect on google images.

Here is what I have:
http://www.1stbusinessneeds.com/tooltip/tooltip.html

The tooltip is offset and is based on the walter zorn tooltip. What's the best way to have the mouseover popup grow out just like google images (with the text), instead of following the mouse?
(I still need it done with the same tooltip - maybe overwrite it, but it must be present to pass the text and image, it's just the positioning and display method of it that I need help creating, any samples would be appreciated)

Comment: Does it have to use that particular plugin or do you just need some mechanism to programatically supply the image and text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at JQuery.

Comment: I don't know how to overwite the tooltip with jQuery to accomplish this effect?

Answer (score 0):

this might be a good start http://jsfiddle.net/ZwhEu/

Comment: There is no text being passed and it doesn't use the tooltip provided!